# C++14: Formatting a list of parameters with known types to a string using functions in a DSL

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

I'm not quite sure what to look for when going about this question, so forgive me if this sounds naive.

The language is C++14 with Boost. I have a known list of structs like this:

```
struct Character { std::string name; };
struct Item { std::string name; };
struct Map { std::string name; };
```

I also have a series of functions taking these structs as arguments and returning `std::string`:

```
std::string name(const Character& character) { return character.name; }
std::string itemName(const Item& item) { return item.name; }
std::string mapName(const Map& map) { return map.name; }
```

What I want to be able to do is this:

```
Character character = {};
Map map = {};
character.name = "David"s;
map.name = "Town"s;
std::string formatted = 
    i18n::localize("Hello, { name($1) }! You are in { mapName($2) }."s, character, map);
assert(formatted.compare("Hello, David! You are in Town."s) == 0);
```

The `localize` function takes a variable list of these known structs and formats them according to a DSL. The intention is to be able to call things like `possessive($1)` to get the possessive phrase for a character, which could differ if the character is the current player, and to allow the same DSL to apply to multiple languages while still keeping the same number of arguments every time.

Because the `possessive` function might not make sense in the context of a different language like Chinese, we might want to call functions for specific languages in the DSL string for that language instead. But because only the objects to be formatted are passed into `localize` we won't know beforehand which one of these functions to call per language without delving into long conditional branches for every single formatting.

It is a user error if the DSL syntax is malformed or a DSL function cannot be applied to a given type, and the `localize` function can throw or something in that case. The DSL environment could have a hardcoded list of functions that things can be formatted with, or perhaps one could do this (although I don't know if this is possible):

```
i18n::register_formatter( name );
i18n::register_formatter( itemName );
```

Or instead if types are an issue:

```
i18n::register_character_formatter( name );
i18n::register_item_formatter( itemName );
```

I know that in Rust you could use enums for this:

```
return match value {
    Value::Character(ref chara) => dispatch_chara(chara),
    Value::Item(ref item) => dispatch_item(item),
    Value::Map(ref map) => dispatch_map(map),
}
```

What kinds of templating needs to happen for something like this using C++14? Is this even possible in C++14?

Comment: Do you need to have different names for the functions? Why not `name(Character const &)`, `name(Item const &)`...?

Comment: My hope is "not necessarily", so users aren't confused by having two different functions for names depending on the object type. But I understand that it may cause issues if a single name refers to two different functions.

Comment: Out of general curiosity, what the heck is a DSL? Damn Small Linux and Digital Subscriber Line both seem out of context.

Comment: @user4581301 Domain-Specific Language :)